# Shorewall with docker

Tags: firewall, docker, shorewall

I'm trying to enable docker support in shorewall (version 5.1.3.2). I've followed guide http://shorewall.org/Docker.html .

However when I try to start shorewall I get the following error:

```
* Starting shorewall ...iptables-restore v1.6.1: Couldn't load target `DOCKER-INGRESS':No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 39
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
ERROR: iptables-restore Failed. Input is in /var/lib/shorewall/.iptables-restore-input
iptables-restore v1.6.1: Couldn't load target `DOCKER-INGRESS':No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 14
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
ERROR: /sbin/iptables-restore Failed.
Terminated
[ !! ]
* ERROR: shorewall failed to start
```

I've tried both to start docker before shorewall or shorewall before docker but I always got the same issue.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to give some more information so someone can reproduce. Off the top of my head: The commands used, Docker version, host OS version, current `iptables -L` and `iptables -L -t nat` outputs, and maybe `ip addr` output.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to docker swarm mode, it creates a DOCKER-INGRESS rule chain, that is not managed by shorewall. As far I can tell, nobody asked for adding that rule chain management in shorewall. There should be a workaround for this, like skipping, or saving/restoring a chain by name in shorewall, like [this](https://blog.discourse.org/2015/11/shorewalldocker-two-great-tastes-that-taste-great-together/)

Comment: this scripts does not work because iptables-save format is changed, I tried by adding | sed 's/-N \(.*\)/:\1 - [0:0]/g' that transform output in the right format.
But then I found that DOCKER-INGRESS problem is related to the way shorewall manage docker rules, saving a rule that refer that chain without including the declaration of that DOCKER-INGRESS chain
And actually that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Officially](https://shorewall.org/Docker.html), Docker swarm is not supported by Shorewall:

> Beginning with Shorewall 5.0.6, Shorewall has native support for simple Docker configurations.
> ...
> Shorewall currently doesn't support Docker Swarm mode.

You may have some luck as I have with the approach described [here](https://blog.discourse.org/2015/11/shorewalldocker-two-great-tastes-that-taste-great-together/). My shorewall rules are too strict, so I had to tweak the script listed in the comments of that article with one that *prepends* rules.

The workaround is to create two files, `/etc/shorewall/init` and `/etc/shorewall/stop`, with this content:

```
rules=/etc/shorewall/.docker_rules
if iptables -t nat -L DOCKER >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo '*nat' > $rules
    iptables -t nat -S | grep -i docker > $rules.nat
    grep '^-N' $rules.nat >> $rules
    tac $rules.nat | sed -n 's/^-A \([^ ]\+\) /-I \1 1 /p' >> $rules
    rm -f $rules.nat
    echo 'COMMIT' >> $rules

    echo '*filter' >> $rules
    iptables -t filter -S | grep -i docker > $rules.filter
    grep '^-N' $rules.filter >> $rules
    tac $rules.filter | sed -n 's/^-A \([^ ]\+\) /-I \1 1 /p' >> $rules
    rm -f $rules.filter
    echo 'COMMIT' >> $rules
fi
```

Then you create `/etc/shorewall/start` with this content:

```
rules=/etc/shorewall/.docker_rules
if [ -f $rules ]; then
    iptables-restore -n < $rules
    rm -f $rules
fi
```

**If you try this**, I must really repeat the [warnings about rules/scripts from the net](https://shorewall.org/shorewall_extension_scripts.htm): **You should carefully review the resulting iptables rules to ensure you have not exposed your network unnecessarily and that the rules work as expected.**

Answer (score 0):

check in shorewall.conf if you have enabled Docker support:

```
DOCKER=Yes
```